# AMD radeon r7m260 driver for ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, radeon, inspiron, 23.10

I’m beginner with linux I use ubuntu 23.10 i need to install the right driver for my AMD R7 M260 graphic card on DELL inspiron I5 4210u any advice for drivers source and installing method …thanks all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)